# Footer overlapping the content DIV (on iPad)

Tags: html, css, ipad

I'm creating a website which seems to work fine with the following method on a desktop computer, but when I test it on an iPad and the content extends over the footer, the footer doesn't get pushed down, but overlaps the content.

My HTML is:

```
<body>
 <div id="wrapper">

  <div id="header">
   ....
  </div>

  <div id="main">   
    <div id="mainuser">                       
      <span id="left"><jdoc:include type="component" /></span>
      <span id="right"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-7" style="xhtml" />                               
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="ft">
   ...
  </div>

 </div>
</body>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
html {     
 height: 100%; 
 padding:0;
 margin:0;   
} 

body{   
 height:100%;   
 margin:0;     
 padding:0;      
 text-align:left;     
}   

#wrapper {
 min-height: 100%;
 position:relative;  
}

#main{    
 width:700px;  
 background:transparent;  
}

#mainuser {    
 margin-top:40px;  
 width:700px;
 text-align:left;
 background:#fff;
}  

#left {
 float:left;
 width: 540px;   
}

#right {
 float:right;
 width:150px;
 text-align:left;
 background:transparent;
 color: #e10000;
 margin-right:5px;
 margin-top:5px;   
}

#ft {
 width:100%;
 height:60px; 
 border-top:1px solid #527988; 
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
 bottom:0;     
}
```

I also tried to insert a div between the content and the footer with clear:both, but it didn't work.

Comment: Your footer has `position: absolute`.

Comment: Yes, if I set it to position:relative, it gets worse and the footer goes all the way up to the top...